# Is it possible to get 'Add User' form in content type?

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to get 'Add User' form in content type?
Can I get the user registration block in structure -> content type

Answer (score 1):

You can

- use Webform-CiviCRM and make a form and then use that as a node, or as a block

I don't quite follow why you would want it as a 'Content Type' which is how i read your question.